# How to merged a static pdf file and a dynamic pdf file using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I found this links [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925616/how-to-merge-multiple-pdf-files-generated-in-run-time), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233129/merging-pdfs-with-itextsharp) and [this](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/12/merging-multiple-pdfs-using-itextsharp.html) and other links as well. All of them uses a stored pdf file to append to each other. And it works, I just don't know how to modify the code to accept a generated pdf file.

How can I achieve to merged a dynamic pdf file (**generated using itextsharp**) and a static pdf file that can be found physically in a folder?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.